# Hibernate collection data lost when two transactions save data concurrently

Tags: mysql, hibernate, concurrency, transactions, jta

I'm facing a strange problem of "losing" data when updating data using Hibernate.

The application is deployed on JBoss AS 7, database connection **isolation level** to **MySql** DB is set to `READ_COMMITED`.

I have entities defined via inheritance like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "element")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ElementEntity {

  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="i_element", nullable=false)
    private Integer iElement;

    @Column(name="hash")
    private String hash;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "element_a")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="i_element")
public class AElementEntity extends ElementEntity {
   ...  // some primitive fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "element_b")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="i_element")
public class BElementEntity extends ElementEntity {
      ...  // some primitive fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "element_c")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="i_element")
public class CElementEntity extends ElementEntity {
      ...  // some primitive fields

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="cElement", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<NodeEntity> nodes;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="node")
public class NodeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "i_node")    
    private Integer iNode;

    @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="i_element", referencedColumnName="i_element")
    private CElementEntity cElement;

  ...  // some primitive fields
}
```

and dao implementation like this:

```
public class ElementDaoImpl implements ElementDao {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ElementDaoImpl.class);

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ElementDaoImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ElementEntity> load(String hash) {

        // nacist vsechny elementy pro SGL
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + ElementEntity.class.getSimpleName() + " WHERE hash = :hash");
        query.setParameter("hash", hash);
    List<ElementEntity> elements  = (List<ElementEntity>) query.getResultList();
    //.. log C element
        return elements;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(String hash, List<ElementEntity> elements) {
        removeElementsByHash(hash);

        for (ElementEntity element : elements) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                if (element instanceof CElement) {
                    CElementEntity cElementEntity = (CElementEntity) element;
                    logger.debug("Storing for hash " + hash + " nodes " + cElementEntity.getNodes());
                }
            }
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            entityManager.flush();
        }

        entityManager.clear();

    }

    private void removeElementsByHash(String hash) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM " + ElementEntity.class.getSimpleName() + " WHERE hash = :hash");
        query.setParameter("hash", hash);
        List<ElementEntity> entities = (List<ElementEntity>) query.getResultList();

        if (entities != null && !entities.isEmpty()) {
            for (ElementEntity entity : entities) {
                entityManager.remove(entity);
            }
        }
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
}
```

dao is created in EJB stateless bean:

```
@Stateless(name=ElementServiceBean.NAME, mappedName=ElementServiceBean.NAME)
@Local({ElementService.class})
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding=ElementServiceBean.NAME)
public class ElementServiceBean implements ElementService {

  public static final String NAME = "ElementServiceBean";

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "coredb_em")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

  private ElementDao elementDao;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
     this.elementDao = new ElementDaoImpl(entityManager);
  } 

  @Override
    public List<ElementEntity> load(String hash) {
      return elementDao.load(hash);
  }

  @Override
    public void save(String hash, List<ElementEntity> elements) {
      elementDao.save(hash, elements);
  }
}
```

Now, in my app sometimes happens situation when save method is called by two different threads concurrently almost at the same time, which causes that data from the collection in `CElementEntity` are somehow lost.

I don't use any form of Hibernate locking. No exception is thrown. Just the data from the "nodes" collection is lost.

So my question is now, how is it possible? Do I use flush and clear methods in dao layer incorrectly?

Or do I really need any kind of hibernate/database locking (but why should I need it when I delete all element rows with given hash before I persist them)?
If I understand it well in CMT is commit performed when the transaction ends.

Here is the log4j log:

```
[2015-01-22 17:02:49,944] 9023579 [Thread-208] DEBUG ElementDaoImpl  Storing for hash ABCDE nodes nodes=[NodeEntity[1], NodeEntity[2]]
[2015-01-22 17:02:50,028] 9023663 [Thread-216] DEBUG ElementDaoImpl  Storing for hash ABCDE nodes nodes=[NodeEntity[1], NodeEntity[2]]
[2015-01-22 17:02:50,727] 9024362 [Thread-208] DEBUG ElementDaoImpl  CElementEntity nodes: []]
```

Thank you for every tip or advice how to improve the code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `@Version` to your entities to enable [optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) and therefore prevent [lost updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

For that your entities need to contain the following field:

```
@Version
private int version;
```

Hibernate will take care of the rest.